# Compile .net dll without specific verstion

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net

I have 2 selfmade DLLs in my .net application. The first DLL is a general one, the second DLL also uses the first DLL. Now whenever I update the first DLL (new version number), I need to recompile also the second DLL. Is it possible to update the first DLL without the need to recompile the second DLL?
Thanks!

Comment: Is your first DLL a .NET or COM ? In any case, it should not matter and no need of recompilation if you have properly referenced them and public interface remains same.

Comment: Both DLLs and the App are all .net. But as soon as I update e.g. First.dll from Release 1.1 to 1.2 and I update my application, Second.dll used in my application complains that First.dll Release 1.1 is not available anymore (because Second.dll was compiled with reference to First.dll Release 1.1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add the reference to the library, make sure you set the "Specific Version" property on the reference to "False".  As long as you aren't referencing a specific version, it won't matter.  You will be able to recompile the dependencies without having to recompile the projects that are dependent upon them.  However, Visual Studio will automatically recompile your project, even if nothing changed except a version number of a dependency.  Technically it's not necessary, though, so you could still run the old exe against the new libraries, etc.

Comment: Hi Steve! Yes, had that already, but Second.dll is still complaining :-( Forgot to mention: It's .net 2.0 .... But the 'Specific Version' property is already available. I'll have a closer look. Good to know that it SHOULD be working this way, I'll try to find my mistake now... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you reference an assembly, and that assembly's interface changes, then yes, you have to recompile the calling code. If, however, you have a common assembly containing the interfaces, then you can change the server assembly all you want because the calling code will still only reference the assembly with the interfaces in it.

And like SteveDog said, set the Specific Version property (of your reference) to False.